# GDB MinGW-w64 how to step over function pointer?

Tags: c++, gdb, mingw-w64

On MinGW-w64, using "next" I can step over functions, but when I try to step over a function pointer call, it always steps in. If I try to step out it says "finish" not meaningful in the outermost frame.

Any ideas on how to get it to step over the function pointer call?

Comment: What platform is it behaving like this?

Comment: @BenVoigt Windows 10 MinGW-w64.